# Change Question Title Because of Answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778982/android-cant-get-spannable-quite-right) about a feature of Android development that was giving me fits.

The answer turned out to be a pretty simple one (you can't re-use instances of the `Spannable` class), but it's one that was not at all intuitive, nor is it specifically mentioned in the documentation.

I'm guessing a lot of other people have struggled with this (and it only shows up in more complicated cases; the simpler cases tend to "work"), so I was thinking about modifying the question's title to point more toward the answer, but wasn't sure about the propriety of that.

Comment: If you think you can give your question a more Google-able title, go for it.

Comment: @pnuts If the question's a duplicate, it should be closed a duplicate, not deleted. Closing as a duplicate means that both the original question and the duplicate can both be Googled, increasing the chances that someone else with the question will find answers in the future.

Comment: Your SO post have very non-informative title and if it would be tag I care about the post would likely be downvoted by mysterious person. Only piece of information you have in title is "Spannable" (repeating tags and "not right" really does not add details). Possibly you don't need anything else and can use "Spannable - broken" as title, but hopefully there is some more usable explanation of effect.

Comment: Wow. You're admitting that you would down vote without commenting? That's pretty frustrating.

Comment: @pnuts I think you missed the "and trial and error" part. I was looking around and was trying different stuff and got it sorted on my own. I don't know of a duplicate question to which to direct my question.

Comment: @pnuts I figured you got the first part from my comment, where I also say I got it figured out by trial and error. There's no answer yet; I asked the correct commenter to make his comment an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @mbm29414 Title with such small amount of information shows "I have what I think most common problem with X. I don't care to search, so reply to me". In C# tag it is very common to see variations of "FormatException bla-bla-bla" questions for example - most of them are the same and show no effort whatsoever - hence get downvote. I don't really see value of adding comments in such case. Since I have no experience in tags you marked your post with I can't reason if "Spannable" identifies problem enough to be rare and searchable... (assuming post have good info than title alone not warrant  -1)

Answer (score 26):

Generally, you want the question title (and tags, etc) to reflect the terms people will use when they have the same problem. The question need not (and probably should not) directly reference the actual solution or even necessarily the root cause, if that's nontrivial to determine.

SO is about giving reasonably competent programmers who run into problems they can't solve the solutions to those problems, and questions are the key to grouping all the programmers with a similar class of problem together so that the solution can be given to all of them at once.

This is why duplicates are so helpful: they combine multiple surface questions that actually have the same root cause together so that anyone with symptoms that match *any* of those gets to see that they're really the same, and how to deal with that.

Therefore, change the question title only to something that better reflects what should be *asked*, and let the answer take care of itself. Something like "Building up Spannables gives wrong styling for most of them" or similar would probably be better.

Comment: If duplicates are so helpful (and I agree with you that they obviously are), then why do SO moderators seemingly wage war against them?

Comment: @MikeWise: To what are you referring, exactly? I've generally seen essentially the attitude in this post among diamonds and the majority of high-rep, moderation-interested users. Certainly there's a strong effort to *mark duplicates accordingly*, but that's exactly what you'd expect to make them useful; there is a significant pressure *not* to e.g. delete duplicates, which is in fact enough to except them from the roomba scripts that can delete closed questions of any other sort under certain circumstances. So, far from waging war, my experience has been that SO mods welcome good dupes.

Comment: Well, that is the impression that comes across. The "marked as duplicate" comes across as a slap in the face, like you did something wrong. It doesn't look optically much different than an "On Hold" and gives one the feeling that you should have nothing to do with that post, and that one has done wrong by not recognizing it as such.

Comment: @MikeWise: Ah, OK. I'm not entirely sure how to fix the impression, but the intention is that duplicates (such as this very question here) should be marked as such and can even be upvoted if they drive traffic to the correct answer well. "Here is your answer! Already!" has been the idea and there's been work done over the years to try to emphasize that more.

Comment: I am surprised you don't have that same impression. Look at this post. Your interesting title and question are completely overwhelmed by the two highlighted yellow bands marking it as a duplicate. The second one even has a proud highlighted list of the vigilant judges  - which frankly no one should be particularly interested in unless it is a blatantly wrong call. It does not seem to me like the intent was to be in anyway positive.

Comment: @MikeWise: If no one is interested in the list of dupe-voters unless they're blatantly wrong, why does that give you the impression of pride and judgmental superiority, rather than the impression of honest accountability? Can you explain more of that?

Comment: Because I see no reason for that second banner at all. There could be a link to that information for those who need it in the first banner. That would take care of the accountability aspect. As it is now it is essentially rewarding people with publicity for marking things as duplicates. Or do you see it differently? Again one of the big problems is that it is optically little different than the On Hold notices that are clearly negative.

Comment: @MikeWise: Given the number of posters concerned about revenge downvotes, the publicity is clearly almost entirely negative. Adjusting it to differentiate it from other forms of closing more might work, though.

Comment: That is a good point. And explains why duplicate markers are mostly high rep users who are immune to a few downvotes. But if revenge is such an issue then duplicate marking must have a negative connotation, right?

Comment: @MikeWise: It does, obviously, mostly among users of lower rep. This divide in perception is rather frustrating and it would be nice to bridge it. (Keep in mind that dupe voters are *always* "high rep", since you need 3k to vote on any question other than your own.)