# Should tags be relocated to the top of question pages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title

I expect that such a fundamental site design question was well thought-out, but I don't understand why tags are listed below a question. I always read the question title and the tags first in order to understand the context of a question. For long questions, this means scrolling to the bottom of the page.

**What would be the pros and cons of having tags at the top of a page vs at the bottom? Would this be the same for asking questions and answering questions?**

When asking a question, I can see the advantages of putting tags at the bottom because the process of writing a question often brings further dependencies to mind and those can be included as tags. However, when reading a question for the first time, I would prefer to read the title and then the tags.

I haven't found a post about repositioning the tags, but here are some about how to write a good title. A good title doesn't need to state all information that would be included in tags.

[Should a post title be modified to fit the problem?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278431/should-a-post-title-be-modified-to-fit-the-problem)

[Change Question Title Because of Answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296040/change-question-title-because-of-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Just FYI, this has been proposed already for [reviews](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311043/show-tags-on-top-when-reviewing-questions), [edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269316/move-tags-field-to-top-when-creating-editing-a-question) and is already in effect in the mobile app.

Comment: The only potential problem I see is people using the tags box for titles, much like they try to make sentences out of tags already. But maybe people would stop adding tags to both the titles and tags areas, so I see it as a net positive.

Comment: So keeping them at the bottom when writing questions and moving to the top I otherwise could help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move tags field to top when creating/editing a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269316/move-tags-field-to-top-when-creating-editing-a-question)

Comment: This seems _slightly_ different in that it proposes moving the tags _everywhere_, not just during creation/editing.

Comment: OP is not advocating moving tags in the creation/editing of questions. Only on the published page so readers of the question don't have to scroll to the bottom of the question to see the tags. I have always wished for this.